# How filter an inner dataframe based on the row of an outer dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

**My goals: **
filter an inner dataframe based on the row (then the values) of an outer dataframe

Let's consider three dataframes:

- first a list of shop with detail about the shop:

```
Shop = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Shop_number': ['SH10','SH20', 'SH30','SH40' ,'SH50','SH60','SH70'],
                    'Shop': ['Chisinau','Milan', 'Paris','Madrid', 'Lyon','London', 'foo']
                    })
Shop
```

[image]

- then a dataframe containing the sales records:

```
Sales = pd.DataFrame({
                        'Shop_number': ['SH20', 'SH30', 'SH50','SH70'],
                        'Amount':[200,400,50,1000],
                        'Type' : 'Actual'
                    })
Sales
```

Which gives:
[image]

then a dataframe containing the budget sales records:

```
Budget = pd.DataFrame({
                        'Shop_number': ['SH10','SH20', 'SH30','SH40' ,'SH50','SH60','SH70'],
                        'Amount':[100,150,200,300,40,500,150],
                        'Type' : 'Budget'
                    })
print(Budget)
```

[image]

Let's summarize data as is:

```
base=pd.concat([Sales,Budget])
base
```

Then what I try to achieve is express Sales and Budget based on Shop table as:

[image]

```
(Shop
    .assign(
        Budget = lambda x : 
            base.loc[(base['Shop_number']=='SH20') & (base['Type']=='Budget')].loc[:,'Amount'].sum(),
        Actual = lambda x : 
            base.loc[(base['Shop_number']=='SH20') & (base['Type']=='Actual')].loc[:,'Amount'].sum(),
        var = lambda x : 
            x.Budget-x.Actual
    )
)
```

Then it work as intended:

[image]

But when I try to make it dynamic then it fails:

```
(Shop
    .assign(
        Budget = lambda x : 
            base.loc[(base['Shop_number']==x.Shop_number) & (base['Type']=='Budget')].loc[:,'Amount'].sum(),
        Actual = lambda x : 
            base.loc[(base['Shop_number']==x.Shop_number) & (base['Type']=='Actual')].loc[:,'Amount'].sum(),
        var = lambda x : 
            x.Budget-x.Actual
    )
)
```

and returns a trace back:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

My question is:

How would you do to make it work?
Would you handle the purpose of this calculation like this or on another more optimal way?

I try what is in the description then it failed.
Of course I tried some make around but it failed as well
can't find the solution

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got the error is because `base` and `Shop` don't have the same length (number of rows). When you use `.assign` with `lambda`, `x` will anonymously replace your `Shop` dataframe. In fact, the filtering can't be done in this case due to length mismatch (impossible comparison in general). You can try this, and you'll have the same issue.

```
print(base['Shop_number']==Shop.Shop_number)
```

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I suggest defining a function that do the filtering job for you. Assuming we have initialized all dataframe as you mentioned above :

```
# this function will be applied to a "DataFrameGroupBy" object and compute results
def get_info(df):
    budget = df.query('Type=="Budget"').Amount.sum()
    actual = df.query('Type=="Actual"').Amount.sum()
    var    = budget - actual
    return budget, actual, var
```

Then you can call the function by applying it to your `groupby` and get the exact result :

```
Shop.merge(
    base.groupby('Shop_number').apply(get_info).apply(pd.Series).reset_index(),
    on='Shop_number',
    how='left'
).set_axis(['Shop_number','Shop','Budget','Actual','var'], axis=1)
```

Output

```
  Shop_number      Shop  Budget  Actual  var
0        SH10  Chisinau     100       0  100
1        SH20     Milan     150     200  -50
2        SH30     Paris     200     400 -200
3        SH40    Madrid     300       0  300
4        SH50      Lyon      40      50  -10
5        SH60    London     500       0  500
6        SH70       foo     150    1000 -850
```

Note that the `set_axis` is just for renaming column names, you can change it and use anything else you want (like `.rename`).

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Boubacar,the aim is to have base on table shop the dataframe contening the sales and budget dynamically filtered , at each different row

Comment: I edited my answer now, I think I understood your problem now. Let me know if it solved your issue.

Comment: Looks great , let me try That tomorrow, i Will tell you how it works , cheers